# Help me understand this Fatal error: Call to undefined function EntityDefaultMetadataController::bundleOptionsList()

Tags: views

With updated modules to recent releases,
Recently this error started appearing when executing 'Modify entity values' in views bulk operations. It happens on all the views in the site.
Indications where to start digging is much appreciated.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function EntityDefaultMetadataController::bundleOptionsList() in /home/cdt/public_html/sites/all/modules/views_bulk_operations/actions/modify.action.inc on line 173`

Comment: Did you run **update.php**, by going to `yourwebsite.com/update.php` after your module update?

Comment: Yes, did that and it makes no difference. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static method [`EntityDefaultMetadataController::bundleOptionsList()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.info.inc/function/EntityDefaultMetadataController%3A%3AbundleOptionsList/7) is a part of [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module that VBO is dependant upon. One of your modifiable entity properties needs this method to retrieve options for the modify operation.

You need to debug why this method isn't available. It's defined in **entity.info.inc** and should be included if the Entity API module is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could have happened, but two are most likely in my experience.  Either something has gone wrong in the registry and it needs rebuilding or an op-cache (APC or memcache usually) is out of date/corrupt.

**To fix the registry use registry rebuild:**
If you have [`drush`](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) installed, download the [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) module for drush: `drush dl registry_rebuild`

Then run: `drush rr`

**To fix the op-cache:** 
Restart the service that controls it (Apache often, but that depends on your server setup), or use the service's built-in clearing mechanism.